# C# IronPython Integration: SetTrace "Kills" Debugger

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, debugging

I am developing a C# application with embedded IronPython scripting, and have found that calling the SetTrace method of the ScriptEngine object will result in the debugger not hitting breakpoints in the script file when debugging the application from Visual Studio 2015 (with Python Tools For Visual Studio installed).

It's actually pretty cool that you can hit breakpoints at all in Visual Studio with so little work. The code below is all you need (in out case, executedvia Task.Run so I believe that means it's on a thread pool thread)

```
var options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options["Debug"] = true;

// Create the engine with the debug option
var engine = Python.CreateEngine(options);

// Read in script from file
var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(filename);

// Adding in out own objects from out ScriptObjects dictionary
var scope = engine.CreateScope();
foreach (var scriptObject in ScriptObjects)
{
    scope.SetVariable(scriptObject.Key, scriptObject.Value);
}

// OnTraceback will check a cancellation token and throw upon cancellation
engine.SetTrace(OnTraceback);

// Execute the script
source.Execute(scope);
```

Actually, I spoke too soon...the above code will work but only if you eliminate the call to SetTrace in the second to last line.

This is important for me...because the methods we call on our script objects (the ones we add to the ScriptScope) are not methods we want interrupted, so we cannot cancel script execution by simply calling the above code in a worker thread and killing the worker thread on cancel. If we allowed that to happen it is quite possible we could leak resources (these methods involve third party code), or that the behavior would be unpredictable (what happens when you tell a motor to move and then kill the thread performing the motion). We use OnTraceback to check a cancellation token, and throw a KeyboardInterrupt exception if cancellation is requested...at least then we know the cancellation is not happening mid-call.

At this point I figured that the debugger itself must be implemented using this traceback mechanism...so when we call SetTrace we are essentially disconnecting the debugger.  Using sys.gettrace from within the python script reveals that this is not the case (gettrace returns None!). Furthermore, if I define a trace handler completely within the python script, I can hit my breakpoints!

It seems that you MUST call sys.settrace(None) at the end of the script or you will cease to hit breakpoints on subsequent executions (even if you call sys.settrace(None) right before you call sys.settrace(yourPythonHandler)...it's like it HAS to be released in within the call to Execute).

This would be a good workaround, except that I have to support legacy scripts with no alteration...and the approach of running a "startup.py" script that sets up the handler, then running the main user script, then running a shutdown scripts that sets the trace to None doesn't work (the quirk above...setup and teardown of tracing must be done in the same call to Execute).

So..the real question is actually two questions:

1). Does anybody know if there is a way to set trace handlers from the C# side that does not kill the ability to hit breakpoints

2). Does anybody know a different mechanism that could be used to cancel script execution that would ensure that we are not in the middle of a call to methods provided by script object provided by the client via ScriptScope.

I have the IronPython source code and thus far can't seem to understand enough of it to see how I am trodding upon the debugger by using SetTrace.

I will continue to dig and post back if I find anything other than frustration, tears and a deep sense of longing for a simpler time when I worked at Jack-in-the-Box!